# Which field type should I use to store true/false values?

Tags: lucene

I want to store a boolean value, but not sure which field type to use.

So something like this theoretically:

doc.add(new ????("numeric", true)
doc.add(new ????("alphatic", true)
doc.add(new ????("alphanumeric", true)

I will be querying using these boolean field types like:

1. search where is numeric only
2. search where is alphabetic only
3. search where is alphanumeric

Any comments on the best approach? (speed/effeciency is important ofcourse)

Answer (score 0):

I think, a `StringField` will do the job since you don't want values - `true` or `false` to be tokenized. Also, with third parameter in constructor , you can choose to store field or be part of only index without getting stored.

JavaDoc ,

> A field that is indexed but not tokenized: the entire String value is
>   indexed as a single token. For example this might be used for a
>   'country' field or an 'id' field, or any field that you intend to use
>   for sorting or access through the field cache.

`new StringField("numeric", "true", Store.NO)`....etc.